# Who are the hosts on Wheel of Fortune on the Nintendo Switch edition?

Tags: nintendo-switch, wheel-of-fortune-switch

On the Wii version of Wheel of Fortune, the hosts were Pat Sajak and Vanna White, just like (most of) the real show. The hosts on the Switch edition seem to be different. The man is definitely not Pat Sajak, the woman doesn't have any voice lines but I do not believe she is meant to be Vanna White. Who are they, and have they hosted the show in real life? I wonder if the woman is even meant to be a real person.

Comment: They don't seem to be named in-game.  The opening cinematic just refers to them as the "hosts".

Comment: Does the Switch version have a credits screen? Maybe they are mentioned there.